# Reactive mongo change streams is resuming with an invalid resume token

Tags: mongodb, changestream

Using the reactive mongo template, I am trying to listen to the mongo change streams for 6 collections for the insert operations only. My code to start listening to change streams is below:

Change streams initiation:

```
//Loop for 6 collections
reactiveMongoTemplate.changeStream(collectionName, changeStreamOptions, MongoChangeStreamEvent.class)
          .doOnNext(changeStreamEvent -> {          
            System.out.println("In doOnNext: Received a new change stream event ");         
          })
          .map(changeStreamEvent -> {    
            //save resume token
          })
          .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
            System.out.println("In onErrorResume of change stream event :: " + throwable.getMessage());
            return null;
          })
          .subscribe();
```

On each new entry, I save the resume token in one of my collections:

```
//Document
public class MongoChangeStreamEvent implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String resumeToken;
  //other fields and getters and setters
}
```

Used change stream options for initiation.
If a resume token exists in the collection, use it.
Else, resume right now.

```
ChangeStreamOptions changeStreamOptions;
    final BsonDocument resumeToken = //getLatestResumeToken, first entry after sorting 
                                     //MongoChangeStreamEvent collection in descending order based on 
                                     //resumeToken

    if (!resumeToken.isEmpty()) {
      changeStreamOptions = ChangeStreamOptions.builder()
          .filter(newAggregation(match(where(OPERATION_TYPE).is(INSERT_OPERATION))))
          .resumeAfter(resumeToken)
          .build();
    } else {
      changeStreamOptions = ChangeStreamOptions.builder()
          .filter(newAggregation(match(where(OPERATION_TYPE).is(INSERT_OPERATION))))        
          .resumeAt(Instant.now())
          .build();
    }
```

Error thrown:

```
Suppressed: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 280 and error message 
'cannot resume stream; the resume token was not found. {_data: 
"825EAFCA12000000162B022C0100296E5A100440284C0343E64ADEB43522FC0552CC1446645F696400645EAFCA12B51E93000716B9300004"}'
```

So far, I have had different experiences with the working of this functionality. Application starting without an existing resume token was always working as expected. Other findings when I had restarted the application with existing resume token are below:

1. It sometimes worked perfectly for all the 6.
2. Just after the restart, it initiated for a few and failed for the remaining.
3. Just after the restart, initiation didn't throw any error. But on insertion of a document in the collection being watched, few/all errored out.

I understand that the change stream is dependent on the oplogs history as quoted in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#resume-a-change-stream). What's more surprising to me was the resume token that gets errored out didn't match any of my existing resume tokens and wasn't present in the oplogs too.

I have verified that the resume token submitted to the reactive mongo template was always correct.

1. Please let me know if I am missing anything.
2. Also, I would love to know how to handle the failure of one/a few out of many change streams running.

Answer (score 0):

```
final BsonDocument resumeToken = //getLatestResumeToken, first entry after sorting 
                                 //MongoChangeStreamEvent collection in descending order based on 
                                 //resumeToken
```

What documentation is this logic based on?

In the current drivers, the driver should have a provision for communicating the resume token for a change stream to the application. There are several sources from which this resume token can come from, and it can also be of different formats potentially. In any event is an opaque identifier, the application should not be *sorting* on the resume token or anything like that.

You could, for example, see *when* you retrieved each resume token and sort on that timestamp, but the only operation appropriate for a resume token is to give it back to the driver to start a new change stream.

Example for Ruby driver: https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-change-streams/#resuming-a-change-stream